# Function inside function starts before any command in kivy and python

Tags: python, function, kivy

I created a simple app to do some stuff with API. This function "kuramac" takes about 2-3 seconds to finish and while it runs, I'd like to disable a button that prevents users to click it several times. Here is my .py code:

```
class WidgetsExample(BoxLayout):  
    # get objects properties from kivy file
    my_text = StringProperty("")
    adress = ObjectProperty(None)
    name = ObjectProperty(None)      
    myBtn = ObjectProperty(None)
    
# function assing to a button
def kuramac(self):
    
    # this should disable the button while function is running
    self.myBtn.disabled = True
    
    inputAddress = self.adress.text
    inputName = self.name.text
    
    # main function posting and object and into a sonicwall 
    response = postIpv4Object(inputName, inputAddress)
    self.my_text = response['message'] + '\n' # + response['comitResponse']

    # this should enable the button while function is running
    self.myBtn.disabled = False


class SonciWallApp(App):
    pass

SonciWallApp().run()
```

If I leave only **self.myBtn.disabled = True** it disables a button after the postIpv4Object function finish. And if I add at the end **self.myBtn.disabled = False**, basically it does nothing. Buttons stay as if nothing happened. I tried to use **sleep.time()** but it didn't do much.

Here is .kv code:

```
<WidgetsExample@BoxLayout>:
    adress:adress
    name:name
    myBtn:myBtn
    orientation: 'vertical'
    color: 1,1,1,1
    Label:
        text:'Dodanie do grupy na sonicu'
        size_hint: None,.5
        height: '10dp'
        pos_hint:{ "center_x": .5}
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        rows: 2
        Label:
            text:'Adres:'
        TextInput:
            text:''
            id: adress
        Label:
            text:'Nazwa:'
        TextInput:
            text:''
            id: name

    Button:
        id: myBtn
        text: 'Wyślij'
        on_press: root.kuramac()
        disabled: root.isEnabled

    Label:
        text: root.my_text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are running `kuramac()` on the main thread. Kivy uses the main thread to update the GUI, but cannot do the updates if you are holding the main thread. To fix that, just run `kuramac()` on another thread. For example, just redefine some methods:

```
def kuramac(self):
    Thread(target=self.real_kuramac, daemon=True).start()

def real_kuramac(self):
    # this should disable the button while function is running
    self.myBtn.disabled = True

    inputAddress = self.adress.text
    inputName = self.name.text

    # main function posting and object and into a sonicwall
    response = postIpv4Object(inputName, inputAddress)
    self.my_text = response['message'] + '\n'  # + response['comitResponse']

    # this should enable the button while function is running
    self.myBtn.disabled = False
```

Comment: Thanks mate! It worked perfectly.

One thing:
    def kuramac(self):
    Thread(target=self.real_kuramac, daemon=True).start()

I think it is from python2, I am using python3 so it should be "threading.Thread".